Crear Dashboard en Power BI con Tabla Calendario y Parametro de Fecha Dinamico
Tengo un SP llamado CantidadClientes_PorProducto el cual tiene un unico parametro de Fecha
El mismo da este resultado
Tipo               CtaCorriente CtaAhorro
CuentaCorriente        18798     4009   
CuentaAhorro           4009      123380 
Credito Consumo        3797      6018   
Credito Corporativo     65        23    
Credito Mediana         236      256    
Credito Micro           1591     4543   


y quiero crear un Dashboard en PowerBI que consulte este SP y poder consultar cualquier fecha
He leido que es creando un parametro en PowerBi y luego crear una tabla calendario pero no tengo idea como enlazarlo
Vengo comenzando con powerBI, ¿Es Posible?, ¿Como puedo hacerlo?

SP es Sharepoint? Supongo que será una lista con una columna fecha, no? Si tienes una columna fecha, una vez añadas la lista a tu modelo de datos, podrás filtrar por ese campo fecha. No es necesario que tengas una tabla calendario solo para eso.
Si no es así actualiza tu mensaje y añade más información, por favor.

SP es Stored Procedure
Procedimiento almacenado en SQL

Has revisado la comunidad de PBI? Por ejemplo este post?
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/Passing-PowerBI-Parameter-To-A-Stored-Procedure/m-p/2284012#M67798
Creo que puede servirte.
